# SpringBoot app does not run with exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am new at Spring Boot so I'm trying to create a simple Crud but I keep getting this error when I run my application

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)

2022-05-24 00:02:13.910  INFO 10611 --- [           main] c.m.crudworkers.CrudWorkersApplication   : Starting CrudWorkersApplication on kalheeso-Aspire-A515-54G with PID 10611 (/home/kalheeso/workspace_sts/crud_workers/target/classes started by kalheeso in /home/kalheeso/workspace_sts/crud_workers)
2022-05-24 00:02:13.913  INFO 10611 --- [           main] c.m.crudworkers.CrudWorkersApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-05-24 00:02:14.033  WARN 10611 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/kalheeso/workspace_sts/crud_workers/target/classes/com/matheusmelo/crudworkers/CrudWorkersApplication.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/home/kalheeso/workspace_sts/crud_workers/target/classes/com/matheusmelo/crudworkers/CrudWorkersApplication.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
2022-05-24 00:02:14.048 ERROR 10611 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/kalheeso/workspace_sts/crud_workers/target/classes/com/matheusmelo/crudworkers/CrudWorkersApplication.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/home/kalheeso/workspace_sts/crud_workers/target/classes/com/matheusmelo/crudworkers/CrudWorkersApplication.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:452) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:315) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.matheusmelo.crudworkers.CrudWorkersApplication.main(CrudWorkersApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/home/kalheeso/workspace_sts/crud_workers/target/classes/com/matheusmelo/crudworkers/CrudWorkersApplication.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:60) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:429) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:57) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

I spose it must be some version problem but I don't know how to fix it. I created the project with STS on ubuntu using mostly default options

Comment: Spring Boot is **exceedingly polite** and tells you **specifically** what the problem is: `ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet`

Comment: Note that if you're new to Spring Boot, do things the easy way (the way we professionals do it): Use https://start.spring.io to generate your skeleton project. Boot 2.3.4 is obsolete; 2.7.0 is the current version and includes an updated version of ASM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have java version problem. Can you check your java version which one you are using.

Comment: <properties>
  <java.version>17</java.version>
 </properties>
my pom.xml has this java version but I'd be okay using java 11

Comment: Ok so I changed to java version 11 and updated project and now it's running but I get these 2 warnings. Can you help me solving them?
```The compiler compliance specified is 11 but a JRE 17 is used```
```Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-11. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment. ```

Comment: If you are using ecllipse. Windows -> preferences and type installed JRE. which JRE it is pointing point it to 11 from your local directory. This warning should be gone then.

Answer (score 2):

You're using an outdated version of Boot (2.3.4, current is 2.7.0), which by default includes an outdated version of ASM that does not understand how to read Java 17 class files:

```
ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet
```

Update your Boot version to 2.7.0.